# Using multiple redux connect HOCs in a single component

Tags: reactjs, redux, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

Hi recently I saw an interesting piece of code.

There was this HOC:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapProps = store => ({
  someProp: store.some.prop,
})

const withSomeProp = connect(mapProps)

export default withSomeProp
```

and then it was used like this:

```
export default compose(
  withSomeProp,
  connect(
    mapProps,
    mapDispatch
  ),
)
```

Is this approach good? Or should I be worried about potential performance issues or any other bugs?

Comment: It gives you a risk of name(s) conflicts you will never know about. 

if you want to keep code DRY I believe [selectors pattern](https://hackernoon.com/selector-pattern-painless-redux-store-destructuring-bfc26b72b9ae) works better and does not have such pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally recommend defining a more complex `mapState` function that extracts both pieces of data that this component needs, rather than defining multiple `connect` definitions just to extract different pieces of data.